# Can a wireless interface act in two modes at the same time?

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, wireless-networking, android

Can a wireless interface act in two modes at the same time ? (e.g. monitor mode and ad-hoc mode) ?

I have an interface which is in ad-hoc mode and I need to capture packets received by this interface using tcpdump which need a monitor mode. How can this be done ?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Did you get solution that used only 1 adapter for monitor+AP (maybe for fluxion tool) ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, [it is possible](http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Documentation/modes) for a device to operate in two modes at once. However, it will depend on whether the drivers and hardware support this functionality.

Comment: Indeed, `iw phy` will output something like this: `valid interface combinations: * #{ managed, WDS } <= 2048, #{ AP, mesh point } <= 8, #{ P2P-client, P2P-GO } <= 1, #{ IBSS } <= 1, total <= 2048, #channels <= 1, STA/AP BI must match`

Comment: @DanielB when I tried to access the iw phy on android it gave me this error "phy : not found" also tried this "iw phy phy0 interface add moni0 type monitor" but i faced the same error, any idea ?

Comment: @user3353241 Replace `phy0` with the name of your interface, if it is different.

Comment: ya @fooot I know I did replaced it. but I'm still having the error

Comment: @user3353241 Android doesn't have a GNU userland. Don't expect anything to work there.

Comment: but @DanielB how to start a monitor mode then ? for a wireless interface on android ? is this possible ? tried googling but I found nothing.

Comment: @user3353241 It’s probably not possible. In the first place, vanilla Android does not even have the `iw` command.

Comment: and I can't install it on the android mobile ? the iw command ?